# Display issue with default menu items in LightSwitch application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

As you can see below, the menu's background is transparent and you can see whatever's behind it. How can we fix this?

I am looking for some code somewhere within the project but I cannot see anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen if you create a quick test application?

I'm still using 2011, so I can't test it. I haven't heard of it happening though.

Comment: I have just noticed that it only happens when I use the Blue shell with the Default theme, but if I switch them around, it doesn't happen. After a reformat, the only VS I have is 2012, so I'm not sure about others yet.